# Error "building static HTML failed for path /" - gatsby, apollo

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, apollo

Since I have added mutation (apollo) to my gatsby project, I haven't tried mutation earlier and I'm struggling with problem below, I'm getting such an error "building static HTML failed for path /" as well as:

```
Page data from page-data.json for the failed page /: {
  "componentChunkName": "component---src-pages-index-js",
  "path": /,
  "result": {
    "pageContext": {}
  },
  "staticQueryHashes": [
    "2589983788"
  ]
}
```

It this a problem with SSR, how should I call mutations? Shouldn't I use apollo for this?

Here's a page index.js where mutation is:

```
   
import * as React from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import gql from "graphql-tag"
import { useStaticQuery, graphq } from "gatsby"

const HomePage = () => {
  const [messageValue, setMessageValue] = useState("")
  const CONTACT_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation CreateSubmissionMutation(
      $clientMutationId: String!
      $message: String!
    ) {
      createSubmission(
        input: {
          clientMutationId: $clientMutationId
          message: $message
        }
      ) {
        success
        data
      }
    }
  `
  return (
    <main>
      <Mutation mutation={CONTACT_MUTATION}>
        {(createSubmission, { loading, error, data }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <form
              onSubmit={async event => {
                event.preventDefault()
                createSubmission({
                  variables: {
                    clientMutationId: "example",
                    message: messageValue,
                  },
                })
              }}
            >
              <label htmlFor="messageInput">Message: </label>
              <textarea
                id="messageInput"
                value={messageValue}
                onChange={event => {
                  setMessageValue(event.target.value)
                }}
              ></textarea>

              <button type="submit">Send it!</button>
            </form>

            <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
              {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
              {error && (
                <p>An unknown error has occured, please try again later...</p>
              )}
              {data && <p>yeah boi</p>}
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    </main>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I have added if statement to render mutation:

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"
```

and:

```
      {isBrowser && (<Mutation mutation={CONTACT_MUTATION}>...</Mutation>)}
```

If someone thinks that there is better way, please comment.